# Пинать, запинаться, распинаться - это однокоренные слова?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, однокоренные-слова

Являются ли однокоренными слова пинать (толкать, ударять ногой), запинаться (замедлять речь), распинаться (долго говорить, доказывать что-то).

Если это однокоренные слова, то почему они имеют такое разное значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, *пинать, запинаться, распинаться* имеют один корень — пин. (Интересный факт: все они родственны таким словам, как, например, *путь, пядь*.)

Изначально глагол *пинать* (восходящий к др.-рус. *пяти*) значил «растягивать, протягивать». Позже от него образовался глагол *запинать* (др.-рус. *запинати*), основным значением которого было «создавать помеху». Затем вследствие такого развития значений глагол-основа *пинать* приобрел вторичное значение «ударять ногой».

Глагол *запинаться* возник путем прибавление возвратного местоимения *ся* к основе *запина/ть* и значил «зацепляться за что-либо ногою». Значение «затрудняться в выговоре слов» является вторичным и возникло на том основании, что, запинаясь, человек «растягивает» свою речь по времени (если зацепиться за что-либо ногой, собственно, время также тянется).

Если вы поняли то, что написано выше, то предположить, как у глагола *распинаться* появилось значение «хлопотать; долго говорить о чем-либо», не составляет труда. (Гл. *распинать* значил «растягивать»).

Вопреки Alex_ander, слова, имеют одно происхождения и принадлежат к исконной лексике. Хотя в старославянском есть когнаты (ст.-сл. *пѧти*, др.-рус. *пяти*).

Источники:
«Этимологический словарь современного русского языка» А. К. Шапошникова;
«Этимологический словарь русского языка» М. Фасмера;
http://www.drevoslov.ru/.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне понятно, что запинаться -  это останавливаться, задерживаться (знаки препинания и запятая - родственные слова). А вот распинаться имеет, как мне кажется, негативно-разговорную окраску (перед кем распинаешься или распространяешься), в то время как подробное изложение с остановкой на деталях  должно восприниматься положительно. И пнуть - это всё-таки толкнуть, а не задержать или остановить.

Comment: @Jasmin «Распинаться» может иметь (или, скорее, имеет) некоторую негативную окраску из-за того, что 1) собеседник далеко не всегда радостно воспринимает долгие, затянувшиеся речи, 2) распинались в давние времена часто перед барином или кем-то, кто находится выше по социальной лестнице; естественно, приятного здесь мало. Не стоит забывать и о распятом Христе (который как раз таки был растянут на кресте): этот образ мог повлиять на судьбу слова. Про *пнуть* я ничего не писал, но да — пнуть = толкнуть.

Comment: @Aer В котором из приведённых источников слово "пинать" (или пнуть, 16 век) этимологически связывают с остальными?

Comment: @Alex_ander во всех (Фасмер не включил статьи с большинством производных глагола *пинать*, однако зачем это, право, нужно?). Позвольте узнать, как связана форма однократного действия *пнуть* с XVI веком?..

Comment: http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/doc/xi-xvii_15.pdf стр. 46-47

Comment: @Alex_ander статья про глагол *пинать* (др.-рус. *пинати*), хорошо. Про пнуть на сс. 46–47 ни слова.

Comment: Пнути - на стр. 114. Любопытно, что у Фасмера нет никакого глагола со значением "ударить ногой", есть только существительное "пинок" без этимол. обоснований - просто отсылка к своей статье по глаголу пну/пять.

Comment: @Alex_ander конечно, у Фасмера есть статья только для *пну* — в значении, которое имело место в древнерусском. «Ударить ногой» есть, к примеру, у Шапошникова.

Comment: @Alex_ander так к чему вы написали 16 век рядом с глаголом *пнуть*, если не секрет?

Answer (score 2):

Этимологический словарь Цыганенко говорит, что исторически однокоренные:

ПИНАТЬ — "толкать" (ногой, коленом). Общеслав. Обозначает многократное
действие (итератив) по др.-рус. глаг. *плти* (через юс малый), пну "растягивать,
протягивать", который отразился в соврем. словах препятствие, распять.
Ср. блр. пяць, пну "давить"; укр. обл. п'ятися "взбираться", "тянуться,
силиться", п'ястися - тожд.

Глаг. *пинать* по оформлению отличается от *плти* сочетанием -ин-, которое через носовой гласный чередуется с **я**, и итеративным суф. -а-. Др.-рус. плти (через юс малый) развился из праслав. *peti, *рьп с и.-е. корнем *pen-/*pin-/*pon- "тянуть", "плести".

Знач. глаг. *пинать* развивалось, вероятно, так: "тянуть", далее — "натягивать", позже — "толкать, ударять". Соврем. *пинать* сохранило только знач. "толкать".

Распинаться от распинать. Распинать — "растягивать" (распинать на кресте); заимствованное из ст.-сл. яз., а распинаться — "долго говорить, затягивать речь".

Пр(ять)пинать — препинать, "препятствовать, задерживать, сдерживать",
"останавливать", от него производное с суф. -ниj-е сущ. препинание, "препятствие", букв. "задержка", которое используется в термине "знаки препинания"; от него запинаться — останавливаться из-за препятствия в речи.

Исторически однокоренные к ним: запонка, запятая, перепонка, путы, пядь, пяльцы, распять. Всё из-за носовых гласных. От одного праславянского корня *pen-/*pin-/*pon-.

Answer (score 1):

*Запинаться* = приостанавливаться. А не просто «замедлять действие». 
*Распинаться* = рассуждать подробно, останавливаясь на каждой детали, как на самой важной. А не только «долго».
*Пинать* = приостанавливаясь, расшвыривать ногами предметы, сор на дороге.

Очевидно, что эти слова одной природы и примерно одного значения.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, у слов **запинаться/распинаться** (a) и **пинать/пнуть** (б) - разная этимология:

(**а**) - восходит к старинному славянскому корню со значением "натягивать/задерживать" ("*распять*" - однокоренное слово) - об этом есть во многих источниках;

(**б**) - иного (возможно, изначально неславянского) происхождения, в русском фиксируется значительно позже; одна из гипотез - от слова со значением "верхней части или носка обуви", которым "пинают": https://www.proza.ru/2015/10/30/1316

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Я где-то читала, что пинать - позднее слово в русском языке, возможно, оно и родственное, но  изменило свое значение.